# Typing the ` symbol

Tags: support, formatting

Let's say I have a question about LaTeX quotation marks.  I want to include the quotation marks

```
``
```

in the in-line "code sample" environment, `like this`.  But I can't seem to escape the ` character, so that it appears within the environment, other than putting it on its own line and indenting...

Comment: Related: [How do I mark inline code?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863/2975)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use double backticks: `` ` ``

What I typed was:

```
`` ` ``
```